# How to define cells formula in VBA with previously defined custom function

Tags: function, vba, excel

In module I defined my custom function `SumByCurrency`. In another routine I would like to define formulas in Cells with this custom function: `Cells(i, j).Formula = "=SumByCurrency(MyString;MyRange)"`. But running this routine always ends with run-time error. It seems to be something how excel handles events.
Does anybody have an idea how to woraround this?
Thanks

Comment: Is the custom function public or private? Is the other sub routine in the same module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax, I think it's wrong:

```
Cells(i, j).Formula = "=SumByCurrency(""" & MyString & """," & MyRange & ")"
```

If **MyString & MyRange** are var in your code...
The Function shall be in a module and Public...
**Note:** I receive an error if I use ";" instead of ",". VBA Convert for me, but not accept I use directly. (Depend of the configuration).

Comment: Thank you. The problem was ";" instead of ",".